# Server side multiple datables showing multiple paginations and search boxes

Tags: php, datatables, server-side-scripting

I have two tables in single page with same class and the data for generated tables are server side processed.

Take a look at the below code.

PHP code

```
<table class="table table-striped display" id="somedetailList" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>some Name</th>
            <th>some Adress</th>
            <th>some Mobile</th>
            <th>some Name</th>
            <th>some da</th>
            <th>some as</th>
            <th>some ds</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($ros as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo  $row->partyname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->address; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->phonenumber; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->total; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->advance; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row->balance; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>


<table class="table table-striped display" id="vehicledetailList" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Party Name</th>
        <th>Party Adress</th>
        <th>Party Mobile</th>
        <th>Driver Name</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Advance</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($balan as $bal) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->partyname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->address; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->phonenumber; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->total; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->advance; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $bal->balance; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And Script for tables is below

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('table.display').DataTable();

  });
  </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdRDw/

Even i tried exactly as this fiddle, then too iam getting the same issue, i'm getting multiple pagination box for each tables.

Please help.

Comment: did you tried using the unique id of each table and use `jQuery('table#id1,table#id2').DataTable();`?

Comment: i tried using class jQuery('table.display').DataTable();

Comment: I tried using different ids too but same result.

Comment: i've copied exactly your code, changed the dynamic content with static content and it works ok, each table has its own pagination box. exist any chance your php code print html tags that breaks the dom? can you provide an online example?

Comment: what do you mean by exist any chance your php code print html tags that breaks the dom ? Please explain so that i can try.

Comment: can you provide an online example?

Comment: I said its working fine when you fiddle it..

Answer (score 0):

Modified the `sDOM` variable in this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdRDw/64/

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: i guess you did not get my question right iam getting multiple instance of pagination and search boxes for both the tables.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the JSFiddle.

Comment: it is working fine in fiddle but when i execute in php file iam not getting expected result.